# How to add limit to input text field in Angular JS

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to add data limit in text field . data should be start from 5.0 and increased upto 5.6 in input field. if user add data above 5.6 into text field than it should show an error. User can add only values from 5.0 to 5.6 only.

Comment: If you are just doing decimals in the 10th range (5.0, 5.1, 5.2... 5.5) you could use a drop down which would be much simpler.

Comment: did you tried with min and max attributes on input ? could you provide some code ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="number" ng-model="vm.value" min="5" max="5.6" step="0.1">
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9r5mj4h6/)

More information at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D

Answer (score 1):

You can use input element

```
<input type="number" ng-model="vm.model" min="5" max="5.6" step="0.1">
```

or you can use regex for validate input when model changed

```
$scope.$watch('vm.model', function(newVal, oldVal){
    if(!newVal || !/^5.[0-6]$/g.test(newVal)){
        /* Show validation here ... */
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use min and max attributes of number input element for simple range validations.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="vm.model" min="5" max="5.6" step="0.1">
```

For any other complex validations, you can write your own custom validation function as below:

```
angular.module('my-app').directive('limitRange', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attr, mCtrl) {
      function myValidation(value) {
        if (value >= 5.0 && value < 5.7) {
          mCtrl.$setValidity('valueCheck', true);
        } else {
          mCtrl.$setValidity('valueCheck', false);
        }
        return value;
      }
      mCtrl.$parsers.push(myValidation);
    }
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
  <div ng-app="my-app">
    <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
      <form>
        <input type="number" step="0.01" ng-model="rate" required limit-range>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
input.ng-invalid {
    background-color: pink;
}
input.ng-valid {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```